# NoneType value in result of processing csv file in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nonetype

My goal is set function to sort and remove duplicates from CSV file, and store it into new variable. My code is:

```
import pandas as pd

file = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\FOOM\\New File.csv")

def file_trimer(n):
    n.sort_values(by = "b", inplace=True)
    n = file["b"]
    n.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

new_file = file_trimer(file)
```

Function is named file_trimer. In result new_file is a "NoneType".

I have two questions:

1. What is the result of processing base file ? Why does new_file is "NoneType" ?
2. How to write values from file_trimer() into new variable ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `return n` in your function.

What is the purpose of `n = file["b"]` line?

Shouldn't it be `n = n["b"]` if you only need that column?

Comment: I'm still learning. It's only I came up with. Was most understandable for me. Thank you for your help.